# Correct way to handle Bi directional 1:m in Green-DAO

Tags: android, android-sqlite, greendao

what is the correct way to insert a new object into a Green-DAO DB when dealing with a Bi Directional 1:m relation?

Lets say, I have a chat application that has a conversation entity and a message Entity. every conversation has a list of messages, and every message has a parent conversation.

what I do as of now is:

```
Conversation conv = new Conversation();
ConversationDao.insert(conv);
List<Message> list = conv.getMessageList();

Message msg = new Message();
MessageDao.insert(msg);

msg.setParent(conv.getId());
list.add(msg);
// SHOULD I UPDATE THE CONVERSATION IN THE DB???
```

it seems to me like I'm not doing this correctly and I would love to get some guidance ad to the correct way to do this.

thanks in advance...

***EDIT:***
as can be seen from my comment, after trying to implement code the way I wrote here, I get a `null` instead of the conversation I was trying to link.
I changed my code a bit and now it looks like this:

```
private static void linkMessageToAuthorAndParent(Message messageObj, Thread parent) {
    List<Message> threadsMessages = parent.getMessageList();
    messageObj.setThread(parent);

    messageDao.insert(messageObj);

    threadsMessages.add(messageObj);
    Log.d("DtabaseHelper.parseMessage", "message was inserted");
}
```

but again, my problem is that I'm not sure the connection is now bi-directional.
 should I now update the threadsDao?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
Conversation conv = new Conversation();
ConversationDao.insert(conv);
List<Message> list = conv.getMessageList();

Message msg = new Message();
msg.setParent(conv.getId()); // Set FK *before* inserting
MessageDao.insert(msg);

list.add(msg);
```

In the [official documentation on relations](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/relations/) there is a section "Resolving and Updating To-Many Relations" giving some background info on this.

Comment: I have to say that this does not work in real life, I tried this in my code and the result of `msg.getConverstaion()` was `null`. I had to use `msg.setConversation(conv)`

Comment: Did you call msg.getConversation() before or after the entity was inserted using the DAO?

Comment: yes, I followed exactly what is written in the documentation, but got a null value. used `msg.setConversation` and it worked, I'm not sure the other direction worked, and that is the basis for my question