# Persisting bi-directional entities with Green-DAO

Tags: android, android-sqlite, greendao

as you can probably remember from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13836417/1056359) about bidirectional relations in Green DAO, I have a chat that consists of conversations and messages.
every message has a parent conversation, and the conversation has a list of messages.

when I try and add a new message, it works perfectly as long as I don't close the application.
This is the code I use for adding a message to an existing conversation:

I now have my code that does this:

```
Conversation conv = getConversation();
List<Message> list = conv.getMessageList();

Message msg = new Message();
msg.setConversationId(conv,getId());
MessageDao.insert(msg);


list.add(msg);

conv.update();
// ConversationDao.update(conv);
```

when I open the application the next time and call `conv.getMessageList()`, the result is an empty `ArrayList`.

what am I doing wrong?

***EDIT:***

I changed my code and now it looks like this:

```
Conversation conv= getCOnversation();

Message msg = new Message();
msg.setConversation(conv);
MessageDao.insert(msg);

conv.resetMessageList();
```

unfortunately, now more than ever (even on same run), still calling `conv.getMessageList()` returns an empty `java.list`.

***EDIT 2:***

here is code for the generator (this is not the real code, but only what is important to the question.

```
Entity message = schema.addEntity("Message");
message.addIdProperty().autoincrement();

Entity conversation =schema.addEntity("Conversation");
conversation.addIdProperty().autoincrement();

Property parentConversation = message.addLongProperty("parentConversation")
        .getProperty();
Property messages = conversation.addLongProperty("messages").getProperty();
message.addToOne(conversation, parentConversation);
conversation.addToMany(message, messages);
```

***EDIT 3***

for now, instead of calling `conv.getMessageList();` I running this line and it work fine.

```
List<Message> messageList = MessageDao.queryBuilder()
    .where(Properties.parentConversation.eq(conv.getId())
    .list()
```

I suspect a major issue for me or greenrobot in the implementation of all this.

is this an issue of running the above code while `Session.runInTx`?

Comment: I'm confused by your data model. How do message, conversion, and thread relate to each other? I did not see what the variable "thread" is. Or should it be "conversation" instead of "thread"?

Comment: @greenrobot, my bad... I didn't change what needed changing, thread == conversation (check edit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problematic section:

```
Property parentConversation = message.addLongProperty("parent")
    .getProperty();
Property messages = conversation.addLongProperty("messages")
    .getProperty();

message.addToOne(conversation, parentConversation);
conversation.addToMany(message, messages);
```

For 1:N relations, you must use **the same property** for both your ToOne and ToMany relation. Try this and regenerate your code:

```
Property parentConversation = message.addLongProperty("parent")
    .getProperty();
message.addToOne(conversation, parentConversation);
conversation.addToMany(message, parentConversation);
```

Comment: from what I recall this is not the way it's documented on the website. worth while to give it another look

Comment: The FOREIGN KEY(...) constraint is not generated even when I do this.

Comment: would be really great if that small snippet (conversation and message is intuitive) would be used as a sample in the "Modelling To-Many Relations" part of the documentation. Using the same property for both is kind of easy to miss.

Answer (score 1):

`conv.getMessageList` returns just a java list. adding a message there will not save it to database. you need to save message to database via `messageDao`.

Comment: as you can see from my code, I insert it into the DB before creating the connection

Comment: yep, but you set msg's conv id after inserting it to db. it should be before. + you should not do list.add(msg). instead, after adding message to db, call conv.resetMessageList . than it will pick up the new message next time you call conv.getMessageList

Comment: that is totally not the way to do this according to the [documentation](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/relations/)

Comment: you can see int he documentation, it says;
> Because of caching, you should add new relation entities manually to > the to-many list of the source entity. 

I would suggest reading the generated code, it should help you clear your mind. I think they should remove the direct list adding example because it creates a confusion.

Comment: can you add your generator code as well? Can you also check if msg.setConversation actually sets msg->convId field. if not, it wont work. maybe you need to set it manually.

Comment: notice my edit, originally, according to the answer by green-robot, I used `setParentConversation` but it only set the id and not linked the original, I changed it to `setConversation` after that (it updates everithing)

Comment: can you please provide some sample code or a link to somewhere? I am going insane here.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: is your conversation persisted **before** calling *msg.setConversation(conv)*? Make sure by introducing a sanity check:

```
Conversation conv = getConversation();
if(conv.getId() == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Conversation not persisted: " + conv);
}
Message msg = new Message();
msg.setConversation(conv);
MessageDao.insert(msg); // Breakpoint here, is parentConversation set?
conv.resetMessageList();
```

If that's the issue, you must make sure that your conversation is persisted, e.g. by calling *conversationDao.insertOrReplace(conv)*.

Once that works, you can also consider replacing *conv.resetMessageList()* with this line:

```
conv.getMessages().add(msg); // Keep same list, also more efficient
```

If that does not help, please debug it and check if msg has parentConversation set before it is inserted (see comment in the code).

Comment: well, I already did those tests, what I saw is: 1. there IS an ID to the conversation. 2. the parent property IS set. 3. `conversation.getMessageList()` returns an empty list. 4. I now have a `messgaeDao.queryBuilder.where(Properties.parentConversation.eq(conv.getId()).list()`. this returns my list. I'm using this now but suspect a more serious issue from my code or yours. thoughts?

Comment: I think we should have this case covered in our unit tests: https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/DaoTest/src/de/greenrobot/daotest/entity/ToManyEntityTest.java

Comment: If you could provide me with a unit test running your scenario, I'm happy to investigate.

Comment: hmmm... don't have xp in writing test units, this might take some time... I'll try and email you directly the workflow (if my boss will approve)

Comment: I sent a link in the contact page on the website